# Why does my button do this?

Tags: javascript, html, function, popup

It goes to undefined then to test.com.

How can i make it go to http://url.com then http://test.com  then http://anotherdesiredurl.com

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function popup(url) {

            var width = 300;
            var height = 200;
            var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
            var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
            var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
            params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
            params += ', directories=no';
            params += ', location=no';
            params += ', menubar=no';
            params += ', resizable=no';
            params += ', scrollbars=no';
            params += ', status=no';
            params += ', toolbar=no';
            newwin = window.open(url, 'popup', 'params');
            if (window.focus) {
                newwin.focus()
            }

            return false;

        }
setTimeout(function() {popup('http://www.test.com/'); }, 8000)


        //-->
        //]]>
    </script>


<head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click Blitch" onclick="popup();"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post your **relevant** code here.

Comment: My code was not properly spaced i tryed editing it but with failure.
Why is this -3 :o

Comment: I guess it's because you provided a pastbin link instead of putting code here

Answer (score 1):

you wrote

```
newwin = window.open(url, 'popup', 'params');
```

I would have expected :

```
newwin = window.open(url, 'popup', params);
```

But i'm not sure it's related to your pb

Answer (score 0):

because you use haven't passed an argument to `popup` function here:

```
<input type="button" value="Click Blitch" onclick="popup();"/>
```

you should either pass an argument, or check in the function if it is undefined, then assign some URL

Comment: How do i pass an argument there?!?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**JavaScript**

```
function popup(url) {

    var width = 300;
    var height = 200;
    var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;          
    params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
    params += ', directories=no';
    params += ', location=no';
    params += ', menubar=no';
    params += ', resizable=no';
    params += ', scrollbars=no';
    params += ', status=no';
    params += ', toolbar=no';
    newwin = window.open(url, 'popup', 'params');
    if (window.focus) {
      newwin.focus()
    }

    return false;

  }

  function openWindows() {
    popup('http://url.com');
    popup('http://text.com');
    popup('http://http://anotherdesiredurl.com');
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Click here" onclick="openWindows();"/>
```

You can change the JavaScript to this if you want to change the location of the same popup after timeout:

```
  function popup(url, win) {

    var width = 300;
    var height = 200;
    var left = (screen.width - width) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - height) / 2;
    var params = 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height;
    var newwin = win;
    params += ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left;
    params += ', directories=no';
    params += ', location=no';
    params += ', menubar=no';
    params += ', resizable=no';
    params += ', scrollbars=no';
    params += ', status=no';
    params += ', toolbar=no';
    if (newwin) {
      newwin.location = url;
    } else {
        newwin = window.open(url, 'popup', 'params');
    }
    if (window.focus) {
      newwin.focus()
    }

    return newwin;

  }

  function openWindows() {
    var win = popup('http://url.com');
    setTimeout(function () {
        popup('http://text.com', win);
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function () {
        popup('http://http://anotherdesiredurl.com', win);
    }, 4000);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me a headache! :D

Comment: Heh, I'm glad that my answer was useful :-)